# how we can pass multiply id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

My view.blade.php code here

```
 <a href="{{ url('p_grid') }}/{{($cat_id)}}/{{$row->sub_id}}">
```

My route code here

```
Route::resource('p_grid', 'BasicController@p_grid');
```

And my BasicController code here

```
public function p_grid(Request $request, $id)
{   
    echo "success";
    if ($id == 1) {
        $r = DB::table('sub_category')
        ->select('*')
        ->where('cat_id', $id)
        ->where('sub_status', '1')
        ->orderBy('sub_id', 'asc')
        ->get();

        $cat_name = DB::table('category')
        ->where('cat_id', $id)
        ->get();

        $count = DB::table('products')
        ->where('sub_id', $id)
        ->count();
       return view('buy-and-sell/p_grid', compact('r','cat_name','count','id'));
    }
```

click on anchor tag to show this error

[image: image upload for help]

Answer (score 0):

The extra parameter in your URL is causing the 404. Laravel doesn't expect the URL to have multiple id's, because you are using resourceful routing. You will need to append your `routes.php` file to account for this:

```
Route::resource('p_grid', 'BasicController@p_grid');
Route::get('p_grid/{category}/{subcategory}', [
    'as'   => 'category-with-subcategory',
    'uses' => 'BasicController@gridWithSubcategory',
]);
```

And make sure you have a `gridWithSubcategory` method in your `BasicController.php` file.

That said, I'd advise you to understand better what Laravel is doing when you declare `Route::resource()`, because I would question how much of it you really need. It's really just a shorthand for registering ordinary routes (see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) for the full list and specifications) like `index`, `create`, `show`, `destroy`, etc. If you want to see the routes your app actually has, after being parsed by Laravel (including routes not in your `routes.php`, which could have been registered by third-party packages) type `php artisan route:list` on a CLI.

Finally, I'd strongly suggest using route names throughout your app for better clarity and portability. The `artisan` command above will give you route names, so you can use something like this in your views:

```
<a href="{{ route('category-with-subcategory', ['category' => $cat_id, 'subcategory' => $row->sub_id]) }}">
```

That way, if you ever want to change your route's footprint, the view won't break (as long as you maintain the parameter requirements).

Answer (score 0):

My view.blade.php code here

```
<a href="{{ url('p_grid', ['category' => $cat_id, 'subcategory' => $row->sub_id]) }}">
```

My route code here

```
Route::get('p_grid/{category}/{subcategory}', [
    'as'   => 'category-with-subcategory',
    'uses' => 'BasicController@p_grid'
]);
```

And my BasicController code here

```
public function p_grid(Request $request, $id)
{
 echo "success";
}
```

success image upload and work done

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr6Kq.png)